# How to put a UISegmentedControl under a NavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I was wondering what the best approach in order to have a UISegmentedControl appears just under the a navigationController just like in the AppStore application:

[image: example image]

The content I what to put in the different views are UITableView just like the AppStore app.

What I was thinking so far was:

- a viewController with the UIToolbar with
  UISegmentedController
- in this ViewController attaching my UITableViews

But what I can't figure out, is how to structure my controller source code files.

Do you have best practice, working examples or at least advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView` property for that. That way it will scroll together with the table view's contents.

To prevent the bar from scrolling together with the table content, I would make it a sibling view (relative to `UITableView`) and place it just above the table view. If you choose this approach you will have the following view hierarchy: controller's view holds the toolbar and the table view. Note that you will have to set up the table view and handle row deselection in `-viewWillAppear:` yourself, duplicating functionality of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: I just gave it a try, but as soon as you scroll the tableView down, the toolbar disappears, and this is not the behaviour I want.

I really would like to have the toolbar always visible.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you want the bar to remain static. I updated my answer.