# UISegmentedControl like in the AppStore app

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, app-store, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I get a `UISegmentedControl` (I think it is one) like in the AppStore app after you chose a category in the categories tab.

I do NOT mean a `UISegmentedControl` on a navigation bar but underneath a navigation bar (see screenshot).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnY7a.png

update:
I just found this question: [How to put a UISegmentedControl under a NavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673714/how-to-put-a-uisegmentedcontrol-under-a-navigationcontroller)

It helps but my question mainly focuses on how to get a `UISegmentedControl` with the same Design as in the AppStore

Comment: That's look like UISegmentedControl with bar style, but I couldn't make it have the same colors. Moreover - on screenshot title text color is different in selected and non-selected state, but it is not so in UISegmentedControl by default. May be Apple used some private apis to achieve that look...

Comment: is there any other possiblity to get the same look... an alternative to uisegmentedcontrol?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about its design, check this link: [Scope Bar for UITableView like App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172794/scope-bar-for-uitableview-like-app-store)

I asked that question a while ago and got some great answers.
I hope it can be useful to you too.

Good luck.